# helix core set workspace root to temp folder

Tags: perforce

Is here a way to create a workspace with a root linked to OS temp folder?

Want to use the same workspace on both linux and windows clients.

Something like `Root:%temp%/root_folder`

Comment: Please don't try to use the same workspace on the two different hosts. You'll really get confused. It's much simpler to have a different workspace for each host.

Comment: We developed a microservice, processing helix core data. It runs on Linux, but developers are working on Windows. It would be nice to have an ability to start it with minimal change

Comment: Perhaps if you shared more information about what you're trying to do, people might have more suggestions about how you could improve your results. The more information you can provide, the better your responses will be.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @BryanPendleton, I wanted to use the same workspace under Windows and Linux. Some constant for temp folder in helix core workspace configuration would be one possible solution. So far it looks like it is not possible.

Comment: It's possible to use the same workspace. This is why there is the `AltRoots` feature in the workspace definition. But the behavior can be just extraordinarily confusing, which is why I was encouraging you not to pursue it. It's a really advanced feature. And the fact that you're considering storing your workspace's data in the OS temp folder makes me think you're just getting started with Perforce, and aren't a really advanced user. Forgive me if I was wrong in that assumption.

Comment: Files need to be in the workspace just for one operation and right after should be deleted - it is a microservice to create or update files in Helix. This microservice will sync a paticular file, perform operation and delet it form workspace. Could you make an answer from your comment. I will check it and accept.

Comment: If it's just one file you want to retrieve, have you considered using `p4 print`? (a) you don't need a workspace, and (b) it's much easier to control the file output location by specifying the `-o` flag to `p4 print`.

Comment: I need to create, update and delete a file. As I understand print gets a file content.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I totally misunderstood your comment. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, env variable expansion is not supported in the client root.

Based on your description of your use case, I think you want to generate a (unique) temporary client for each operation and delete it when you’re done.  Trying to reuse one client spec just opens you up to really unpleasant race conditions.

Comment: creating a temporary client would be great, how can I do that? can I use it for CRUD operations?

Comment: Yes, CRUD is the idea here.  Make a normal client, use it, delete it when you’re done.  Creating a client has pretty low overhead; it’s only a small handful of database entries if you’re only syncing one file to it.